# Can't launch Spyder - 'Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received'

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I can't run Spyder from windows shortcut. It doesn't open at all. After that I tried running it from Anaconda navigator which shows the following errors. I have uninstalled the Spyder and reinstalled it also. It happened after tried installing Opencv in Anaconda.

```
[1205/235251.482:ERROR:icu_util.cc(178)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
[1205/235251.483:FATAL:icu_util.cc(297)] Check failed: result. 
Backtrace:
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FFA2A88D261+125633]
QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler::qt_static_metacall [0x00007FFA2A822E63+5555]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FFA2AB7A3B5+3193877]
QtWebEngineCore::AuthenticationDialogController::qt_static_metacall [0x00007FFA2A8026F5+7629589]
QtWebEngineCore::WebContentsAdapter::webContents [0x00007FFA2A0A8351+20433]
QtWebEngineCore::WebContentsAdapter::webContents [0x00007FFA2A0A89BE+22078]
QtWebEngineCore::WebContentsAdapter::WebContentsAdapter [0x00007FFA2A09C038+56]
QWebEngineHistoryItem::url [0x00007FFA55253547+423]
QWebEnginePage::QWebEnginePage [0x00007FFA55253893+147]
QWebEnginePage::QWebEnginePage [0x00007FFA552537DD+45]
(No symbol) [0x00007FFA5C9483C4]
(No symbol) [0x00007FFA756313BF]
type_call [0x00007FFA5364F8A7+167] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\objects\typeobject.c:972)
_PyObject_FastCallKeywords [0x00007FFA5364F63A+378] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\objects\call.c:199)
call_function [0x00007FFA53657709+1017] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\python\ceval.c:4619)
_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault [0x00007FFA53657CEF+1199] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\python\ceval.c:3125)
_PyFunction_FastCallDict [0x00007FFA53640C9D+221] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\objects\call.c:322)
slot_tp_init [0x00007FFA5363EDF3+315] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\objects\typeobject.c:6636)
type_call [0x00007FFA5364F8A7+167] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\objects\typeobject.c:972)
_PyObject_FastCallKeywords [0x00007FFA5364F63A+378] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\objects\call.c:199)
call_function [0x00007FFA53657709+1017] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\python\ceval.c:4619)
_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault [0x00007FFA53657CEF+1199] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\python\ceval.c:3125)
_PyFunction_FastCallDict [0x00007FFA53640C9D+221] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\objects\call.c:322)
slot_tp_init [0x00007FFA5363EDF3+315] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\objects\typeobject.c:6636)
type_call [0x00007FFA5364F8A7+167] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\objects\typeobject.c:972)
_PyObject_FastCallKeywords [0x00007FFA5364F63A+378] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\objects\call.c:199)
call_function [0x00007FFA53657709+1017] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\python\ceval.c:4619)
_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault [0x00007FFA53657CEF+1199] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\python\ceval.c:3125)
_PyFunction_FastCallDict [0x00007FFA53640C9D+221] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\objects\call.c:322)
slot_tp_init [0x00007FFA5363EDF3+315] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\objects\typeobject.c:6636)
type_call [0x00007FFA5364F8A7+167] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\objects\typeobject.c:972)
_PyObject_FastCallKeywords [0x00007FFA5364F63A+378] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\python\pythonrun.c:432)
PyRun_AnyFileExFlags [0x00007FFA537B513B+99] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\python\pythonrun.c:85)
pymain_run_file [0x00007FFA5370137B+191] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\modules\main.c:433)
pymain_run_filename [0x00007FFA53701423+111] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\modules\main.c:1613)
pymain_run_python [0x00007FFA53670A24+390720] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\modules\main.c:2873)
pymain_main [0x00007FFA536113A5+41] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\modules\main.c:3415)
Py_Main [0x00007FFA53611052+82] (c:\ci\python_1572550317365\work\modules\main.c:3437)
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please remove Anaconda and the directory where it was installed and reinstall it again. I think you have no other choice here.

Comment: Getting the same error when opening Spyder. Were you able to find a resolution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error when opening Spyder via the command line using `spyder --debug-info verbose`.

The fix was actually quite simple, based on the [recommendation here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72228).

Point 3:

> Ensure the presence icudtl.dat file inside application directory

Simply copying `icudtl.dat` fixed the issue.

- From: `/c/anaconda3/envs/py37/Library/resources/icudtl.dat`
- To: `/c/anaconda3/envs/py37/`

#### Upstream Fix

Before receiving this error, I received an error stating: `Could not find QtWebEngineProcess.exe`

The fix for this was based on [this recommendation](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-626).

> Copying the following files to C:\Python36 (python's root folder) seems to be a workaround

> C:\Python36\qtwebengine_devtools_resources.pak
> C:\Python36\qtwebengine_resources.pak
> C:\Python36\qtwebengine_resources_100p.pak
> C:\Python36\qtwebengine_resources_200p.pak
> C:\Python36\QtWebEngineProcess.exe

Answer (score 0):

Actually, instead of copying the files to the Python root directory you should check the qt.conf file in the Python root directory whether it links to the correct subdirectories (cf. the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67553849/4340584)). If you get the error messages they are most likely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda:

1. Uninstall Spyder
2. Uninstall Qt Console
3. Reinstall Spyder (select Spyder >=5.4.3)