# Pyinstaller: Could not find QtWebEngineProcess.exe for PyQT5 Web Application

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qtwebengine

I am developing a web application which displays a folium map. The web app has 3 tabs and each tab has a **QtWebEngineView** widget added into them.

I am trying to create a standalone .exe file for my web application. So I have used Pyinstaller to convert my project into a single .exe file. I already had to make some changes in my spec file to solve a previous issue (fixed). This is how the spec file looks

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\Bus_Stop_Finder'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('input\\stops.txt', 'input'), 
             ('input\\Suggestions.xlsx', 'input'),
             (".\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\branca\\*.json","branca"),
             (".\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\branca\\templates","templates"),
             (".\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\folium\\templates","templates"),
             ],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
          
            
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='main')
```

On running `Pyinstaller mainspec`, the dist folder and main.exe file is created but once I run the the main.exe file, I am getting this error:

```
Could not find QtWebEngineProcess.exe
```

I have tried reading through the Qt Documentation for deploying Qt WebEngine Applications and noticed that

> The WebEngine process is executed for each QWebEngineView or
> WebEngineView instance

I am not sure, where I have to make a modification or correction. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: I was running into the same issue and ended up in using [nuitka](https://nuitka.net): `nuitka --standalone --plugin-enable=qt-plugins <your_script.py>` and [wrappe](https://github.com/Systemcluster/wrappe) as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/issues/230#issuecomment-716303087)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and finally fixed it. (Python 3.9.5 & PyQt5.15.4)

Your problem is not related to the spec file modifications.

The root of the problem is the structure of generated files.
more precisely in `dist` directory.

The QtWebEngineProcess.exe that the *app_name*.exe is looking for, it exists in `dist>{app_name}>PyQt5>Qt>bin` path, but this app cannot access it. to create this access, the following tasks must be performed:

1. Create text a file in `dist>{app_name}` directory and name it **qt.conf**
2. Enter the following text in it

   ```
   [Paths]
   Prefix = PyQt5/Qt/
   ```

Now the main.exe runs without any problems :)

Comment: The last Slash is optional and has no effect on the result.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, tried Saam's fix but apparently, the last slash is added via hooks. I add a qt.conf file in my dist/appname
dir

```
[Paths]
Prefix = PyQt5/Qt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[Paths]
Prefix = PyQt5/Qt/
```

You have to create a `qt.conf` file with the above details in it, and this file should be with your app.
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfqF6.png)
[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZzJB.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
[Paths]

Prefix = PyQt5/Qt/
```

[After debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vxgy.png)

The path is correct but the file name after debug is created as `'Qt5'`. It should be changed to `'Qt'`

[Change folder name 'Qt5' to 'Qt'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCnNK.png)