# Could not find QtWebEngineProcess.exe

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, cx-freeze, qwebview, qwebengineview

I was building an application(Equation solver) in PyQt5 which contains two frames.
The first [frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwde6.png) works just fine but the 2nd frame contains a QWebEngine widget **which worked fine when I directly ran it from the code in my code editor** but when I converted into an .exe
file using cx_freeze, on running the second frame I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miIQl.png) saying "Could not find QtWebEngineProcess.exe" .

I did a little bit of digging myself and found out that its quite common actually, even found a question similar to this in stack overflow : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67060913/pyinstaller-could-not-find-qtwebengineprocess-exe-for-pyqt5-web-application).
I tried adding the `qt.conf` file but to no avail, the error still persists.

I am at a loss here, been working on this for so long and now this error really ruined the flow.
I would be very grateful for any kind of help.
Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same problem when freezing my project using PyInstaller. I am using Python 3.10.7, PyQt 5.15.7, PyInstaller 5.6, and PyQtWebEngine 5.15.6.  I using LInux: Ubuntu 22.10.  I have also tried creating a qt.conf file as suggested elsewhere, but have had no luck.